# Construct 9 degrees in a specific way(from Kiselev's Planimetry)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm reading this book Kiselev's Planimetry(http://www.cimat.mx/ciencia_para_jovenes/bachillerato/libros/kiselev/[kiselev]book1_planimetry.pdf), and there is this problem (problem 444, page 174 of the book) on chapter 8, Application of Algebra to Geometry, that asks to construct 9 degrees. By the way in his book d=90 degrees. Now, I would, usually, assume, that the chapter lessons motivate the solutions to chapter problems, and this assumption helps me most of the time. Now, how does this 3-page chapter that talks about using the concept of unit measure, algebra, and proportionality,  help me in constructing this problem. Anyway, perhaps any other method might help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right then we have the following problem.

> Construct the angle in $9^{\circ}$.

Use $\sin18^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}$ and construct the bisector of the angle with measured angle $18^{\circ}$.

Comment: Ok. I think this is it. I'll try to construct from this number. I was too preoccupied with 90 degrees and dividing it 10.

Comment: I think I have constructed it. The moment I left the chapter on trigonometry I forgot all about them. =(

Comment: @tighten I am happy that I helped to you.

Answer (score 0):

We can get a $9°$ angle fairly efficiently by adapting Ptolemy's construction of a regular pentagon.

Begin with line $l$.  Construct a libe $m$ perpendicular to $l$ which intersects $l$ at point $O$.  Center the compasses on $O$ and construct s circle, circle $O$, which intersects $l$ at $A$ (either of two possible solutions) and intersects $m$ at points $B$ and $C$ (use both of these points).  Bisect segment $OA$ of $l$ to obtain point $D$.  Center the compasses at $D$ and construct an arc through $B$ which intersects $l$ at a point $F$ outside circle $O$.  Center the compasses at $B$ and construct an arc through $F$ which intersects circle $O$ at $G$ within arc $AC$.  Bisect $\angle AOC$ to obtain ray $OH$.

Then $\angle BOG$ measures $144°$, $\angle BOH$ measures $135°$, and their difference $\angle GOH$ measures $9°$.